# Can't seem to find the instance of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I created a CKEitor dialog box with the following code

```
<textarea name="content_html" id="editor1" rows="6" cols=""></textarea>
<script>
        window.onload = function() 
        {
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        };
</script>
```

And the Dialog works fine. But when i try to set data for the current instance

```
<script>
      CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData("hello");
</script>
```

I get a javascript error : CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 is undefined

Comment: my guess: you are waiting until the window has loaded before setting editor1... but the code in your second script gets run immediately (ie before the window has been loaded and thus before editor1 has been set)

Answer (score 0):

Oops! My Mistake. Solved!

```
<textarea name="content_html" id="editor1" rows="6" cols=""><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
```

This solved it!